# I Read That MVC "Embraces The Web" And Web Forms "Abstracts The Web" - What Does This Mean?

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms

Can anyone explain briefly what it means that MVC embraces the Web while Web Forms abstracts the Web?

Comment: It means that some people have too much free time in their hands, and they are doing poetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

briefly,

MVC respect the true stateless nature of HTTP and communicate in a true request-response model.

on the other hand WebForm abstracts some features to provide a simulated stateful model for Web developers (e.g: viewstate, postbacks, and an overall event-driven paradigm)

Comment: thank you for explaining it so succinctly...i get it now.